# Overthinking markets

Tags: meaning

I have a question about this article regarding marketing.
 https://blog.ycombinator.com/toy-markets/

> While most successful startups that make one of these arguments will eventually raise large sums of money, the fundraising environment at a company’s founding can have a large impact on it’s [sic] path.
>   One of the stranger things happening in the startup world right now is the ever-rising amount of capital available to startups at all stages of life.
>   This seems to be reinforcing the dangers of *overthinking markets*, as founders and investors each try to justify larger amounts of investment and the pricing that goes along with that.

What does "overthinking markets" mean in this context?

Comment: "its path" not "it's path".

Comment: And what does "reinforcing the dangers" mean?

Answer (score 2):

To **overthink something** is to attribute to it greater complexity and nuance than (the speaker feels) it actually has.